# Logging every perl script executed by Apache

Tags: apache, perl, logging

Is there a way to configure apache to log every perl script execution?

Or on the other hand to configure perl to log it's own executions.

About the second option I've read about perl wrappers, but also have read that it is tricky, since I only want to log the ones from apache maybe it is easier to configure apache to do it.

Made StackOverflow and Google searches and couldn't find this specific information.

Cheers.

Comment: access.log should have the requested urls. Wouldn't that be sufficient?

Comment: There are four ways you can get `perl` to log its executions: 1) modify the `perl` source. 2) compile `perl` with the setting that enables the execution of a "siteconfig" script at start. 3) replace `perl` with a wrapper, 4) set env var `PERL5OPT` to `-MSomeModule` where SomeModule performs the logging. /// In each of these cases, you can check if the parent process is apache.

Comment: [mod_cgi](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_cgi.html), the apache module that launches CGI scripts, does have some debugging log facilities that can be enabled. The docs recommended against using them in prod.

Comment: If you have a perl script "print STDERR 'abc'" then, when invoked via apache, it will log to /var/log/apache2/error.log (assuming you have apache.conf LogLevel set to include errors).

Comment: Hi.
Based on the suggestions I managed to install MDevel::PerlLog that works pretty good on the shell, but I'm not being able to get it to work for apache started scripts.

Notes:
- On the shell I used export PERL5OPT="-MDevel::PerlLog=/tmp/perl.log,all" to get is to work;
- On apache I tried adding (to httpd.conf) this directives:
PerlSetupEnv On
PerlSetEnv PERL5OPT "-MDevel::PerlLog=/tmp/perl.log,all"
Or
SetEnv PERL5OPT "-MDevel::PerlLog=/tmp/perl.log,all"
But it does not log anything
Have the the perl.log file with permissions that let apache write to it.
Any Ideas?